# MCU control relay with an "all good" signal

Tags: microcontroller, circuit-design, switches

*I didn't find any documentation with the best practices in that subject.
My MCU will have to read the states of some external (outside PCB) NO, NC switches and I don't want to be exposed directly to the "outside world". Is there some documentation how an MCU can safely interface with external switches?
One way I was thinking is the use of optocouplers. Any suggestions?
And what kind of filtering should I use? The switches will be close to an AC motor.*

UPDATE QUESTION:
I am updating the question I hope it doesn't mess things up.

I included a schematic below with the functionality I want to implement.

The CLOSED_DOOR_NO is the contact of the limit switch that it will have 0 V (I miss a pull-down I think there) if the door is not closed and the MCU it will be able to drive the BJT.

When 0 V is not present, the driver will stop the current to BJT even if the MCU GPIO (CLOSE_RELAY) is still low.
I searching for a circuit that has this functionality.

[image: Relay driver with all good signal?]

[image: MCU Reads the state of door]

[image: Terminal for the limit switch]

Comment: Yes, opto-couplers are usually a good choice (my suggestion).

Comment: you can just connect them, if you want, but I suppose you want to protect the MCU from misconnections etc

Comment: Can I ask how far is it between the MCU system and the switches?  How rapidly do you need to read them?

Comment: @jonathanjo around 1 meter. Not very rapidly. It is an automation for a garage door. I am thinking also the switches must be able to stop the motor without the MCU. But the MCU needs to read the states anyways.

Comment: If you draw a diagram that's the way to get the best out of EE.SE .. there are so many ways to do what you want, and a sketch really helps nail down your difficulties and goals to answerable points.